# How to permute a rust simd vector by another variable vector?

Tags: rust, simd

Ok. So I've recently started learning rust by rewriting my program to rust though I might have started too hard because I am using portable simd module in rust and I am having restless nights of finding functions to use. Today I tried looking for a way to permute i8x16 vector by another i8x16 vector, like a _mm_shuffle_epi8 from SSE, but sadly didn't find anything.

Please help me find function from std::simd to permutate vector by another variable vector.

Preferably as fast as possible and I want to keep it SSE or AVX but not AVX2 or bigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this issue, it is not yet implemented for [`std::simd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/simd/index.html): [Introduce "dynamic swizzling" into LLVMIR and Rust intrinsics](https://github.com/rust-lang/portable-simd/issues/242).

For now, you will have to resort to calling [`std::arch::{x86,x86_64}::_mm_shuffle_epi8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/x86/fn._mm_shuffle_epi8.html) (or whatever you were after) manually, with `cfg`-wrapping of course if you want it to stay portable.